# Can Parse Subclassing handle multiple layers on inheritance?

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I'm creating subclasses of `PFObject` and want to know how I can organize my code. Let's say I want to do this:

```
@interface Person : PFObject<PFSubclassing>

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *firstName;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *lastName;

@end



@interface Employee : Person

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSNumber *salary;

@end
```

Would Parse know how to handle this? I know `Person` would work just fine, but I'm not sure about `Employee`. I'd like to be able to call `[(Employee *)myEmployee firstName]` and have it work properly. My actual usage will be quite a bit more complicated, which I why I want to keep all like-methods in the same place.

Comment: Just to clarify, you have a Person table on Parse.com, and saving an Employee will save to the Person table, correct?

Comment: Actually I think I want them in separate tables. In my actual implementation Person would probably be an abstract class, so it might not ever hit Parse at all. Only the subclasses would.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your answers above, yes, this can be done.

However, there are some pitfalls to avoid surrounding how Parse handles subclassing. The easiest thing here is to read through this thread at Parse.com that explains errors and workarounds to ensure harmonious subclassing:

https://www.parse.com/questions/what-does-this-error-mean-subclasses-of-subclasses-may-not-have-separate-parseclassname-definitions

Best of Luck!

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the info. Looks like because I want my top class to be abstract, I should just not implement the parse class name method there and only do it in my concrete classes.